# List with out using join()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def concat_list(str_list):
    str_list = []
    for i in range (0, len(str_list):
```

Wants to create a function that accepts as a input a list of strings and extracts a single string, which is actually all strings connected. I do not want to use the join ()

Comment: why do you not want to use join?

Comment: As you are using an iterable, better make use of `.join()`....

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this recursively,

```
def concatlist(str_list):
    if str_list == []:
        return ""
    else:
        return str_list[0] + concatlist(str_list[1:])
```

Note this might not be the right slicing in python :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this

```
def concat_list(str_list):
    combined_string = ""
    for str_item in str_list:
        combined_string = combined_string + str_item
    return combined_string
```